# Как правильно юзать getchar в СИ ,чтобы окно программы закрывалось при нажатии enter?

Tags: c

Почему программа закрывается сразу же?хотя getchar используется.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x=0, y=0, z=0;
    printf("Please,enter the two numbers\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &x, &y);
    z = x + y;
    printf("Result: %d", z);
    return 0;
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Например перенести `getchar()`, выше `return 0;`

Comment: Ваша программа - консольное приложение. У нее нет никакого "окна программы" и ни открываться, ни закрываться ничего не должно.

Comment: @ヒミコ, Ничего не поменялось.

Comment: @AnT ,имеется в виду,чтобы консольное приложение закрывалось при нажатии enter.

Comment: @fxck.phx: Традиционно консольное приложение запускается из окна консоли. Потому оно и называется "консольным". Еще раз: в таком приложении ничего не должно открываться и ничего не должно закрываться.